# Cannot display more than one popup simulteneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I want to show 4 popup windows, at the same time, which show 4 different flash slides after a respective image button is clicked.

I used `JavaScript` to make the popup window but cannot complete the rest of the image button. When i click on the button random flash slide plays.

Please refer below code :-

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
<link href="ddmenu/ddmenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico"/>
<script src="ddmenu/ddmenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("[id*=a]").live("click", function () {
            $("#dialog26").dialog({
                title: "DMD Officers",
                height: 700,
                width: 1000,
                buttons: {
                    Close: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("[id*=b]").live("click", function () {
            $("#dialog27").dialog({
                title: "Outsourced Photographs",
                height: 700,
                width: 1000,
                buttons: {
                    Close: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("[id*=c]").live("click", function () {
            $("#dialog28").dialog({
                title: "DMD Dog Squad",
                height: 700,
                width: 1000,
                buttons: {
                    Close: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("[id*=d]").live("click", function () {
            $("#dialog29").dialog({
                title: "Snake awareness campaign",
                height: 700,
                width: 1000,
                buttons: {
                    Close: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <table>
<tr>
            <td colspan="3" class="auto-style9">
                <nav id="ddmenu">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="Home.aspx" target="_blank">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.ril.com/OurBusinesses/Global-Corporate-Security/Security-Services.aspx" target="_blank">About Us</a></li>
</ul>

</nav>
</td>  
</tr>

<tr>
                    <td style="border-style: solid; border-color: #996600;">
                        <asp:imagebutton id="a" runat="server" height="200px" imageurl="~/Images/officer.jpg" width="200px" />
                        <div id="dialog26" style="display: none;">
                            <embed src="Videos/DMD Officers final.swf" height="1000px" width="1000px" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td style="border-style: solid; border-color: #996600;">
                        <asp:imagebutton id="b" runat="server" height="200px" imageurl="~/Images/outphoto.jpg" width="200px" />
                        <div id="dialog27" style="display: none;">
                            <embed src="Videos/Outsourced photographs.swf" height="1000px" width="1000px" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td style="border-style: solid; border-color: #996600; text-align: center;">
                        <asp:imagebutton id="c" runat="server" height="200px" imageurl="~/Images/Dog.jpg" width="200px" />
                        <div id="dialog28" style="display: none;">
                            <embed src="Videos/DMD Dog Squad 1.swf" height="1000px" width="1000px" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td style="border-style: solid; border-color: #996600; text-align: center;">
                        <asp:imagebutton id="d" runat="server" height="200px" imageurl="~/Images/SankeAwa.jpg" width="200px" />
                        <div id="dialog29" style="display: none;">
                            <embed src="Videos/Snake awareness campaign.swf" height="1000px" width="1000px" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: may be make your question more clear, as to which part of your program is failing and which part you need help with. You can also place a Jsfiddle to demonstrate the issue

Comment: Do Not Use `LIVE` for binding event's. Use `on` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This code here `$("[id*=btnPopup]")` is means that is capture all buttons that contains the `btnPopup` !, since the rest buttons contains that because of the name (**btnPopup2**,**btnPopup3**,**btnPopup4**) you have capture all with the same (first) code, and what ever you press only the first is fired.

So rename the first button to **btnPopup0** if you like to use this code as it is and make it work.

Reference : 
https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

But I see more bugs...

in this line `$("#dialog").dialog({` that exist on every call, is still call the same part of the page to make it dialog, but I see that the other parts have names like **dialog1**, **dialog2** etc... so this is something that you must fix also.

Answer (score 0):

lots and lots of mistake in your code !!! .Let me point out one by one.

**1.** `$("[id*=a]").live("click"` :  Similar code exist in other 3 sections. **Do Not Use Live** to bind events. Its deprecated, and deprecated for good reasons. Taken from the doc

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

Also in your scenario `[id*=a]` is not required. Simply `id=a` would be sufficient.

[**live() jquery API Document**](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

**2.** `$("#dialog").dialog({` : You have the same code in other 3 sections as well. You are binding events to the same id. Which is a `BIG NO`. Do not use same Id's **Id's has to be unique in the entire DOM**. You can make use of class. Just put the same class name to all the divs and then bind events using the class name.
 - When you bind events by using `ids` Jquery will find the **first** element with that id in the DOM (reading from top) and binds the event to onle that element.

---

---

You are repeating the same script logic multiple times, `make it Generic`. So cleaning up your HTML and SCripts, Below is what you actually need.

HTML

```
    <tr>
      <td style="border-style: solid; border-color: #996600;">
        <asp:imagebutton id="a" class="imageDialog" runat="server" height="200px" imageurl="~/Images/officer.jpg" width="200px" />
        <div class="dialog" data-dialog-title="DMD Officers" style="display: none;">
          <embed src="Videos/DMD Officers final.swf" height="1000px" width="1000px" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="border-style: solid; border-color: #996600;">
        <asp:imagebutton id="b" class="imageDialog" runat="server" height="200px" imageurl="~/Images/outphoto.jpg" width="200px" />
        <div class="dialog" data-dialog-title="Outsourced photographs" style="display: none;">
          <embed src="Videos/Outsourced photographs.swf" height="1000px" width="1000px" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="border-style: solid; border-color: #996600; text-align: center;">
        <asp:imagebutton id="c"  class="imageDialog" runat="server" height="200px" imageurl="~/Images/Dog.jpg" width="200px" />
        <div class="dialog" data-dialog-title="DMD Dog Squad" style="display: none;">
          <embed src="Videos/DMD Dog Squad 1.swf" height="1000px" width="1000px" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="border-style: solid; border-color: #996600; text-align: center;">
        <asp:imagebutton id="d"  class="imageDialog" runat="server" height="200px" imageurl="~/Images/SankeAwa.jpg" width="200px" />
        <div class="dialog" data-dialog-title="Snake awareness campaign" style="display: none;">
          <embed src="Videos/Snake awareness campaign.swf" height="1000px" width="1000px" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

**Note:**  `I added a class to all the imageButton`, `And then changed the div id to class`. Also added `data-dialog-title` attribute to hold the titles for the dialog. [**More About data Attribute**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) You will see its usage below.

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $.each('.dialog',function(){ //loop all the div's and apply plugin for all of them
    $(this).dialog({
      title: $(this).data('dialog-title'), //extract the title here.
      height: 700,
      width: 1000,
      buttons: {
        Close: function() {
          $(this).dialog('close');
        }
      }
    });
 });


  $(".imageDialog").on("click", function() {
     $(this).closest('td').find(".dialog").dialog( "open" ); //this is how you open the dialog, taken from the plugin site.
  });
});
</script>
```

- On document ready apply the dialog plugin to all the div's with class `dialog`
- Bind event to all imageButton by just using class selector `.imageDialog`
- trace up to the parent td, then trace down to find the div with class name 'dialog' and open it.

Comment: i have followed your code but when i click on the image button popup window is not coming, when i change `on` to `live` its working but when i click on the same image button second time popup window is not coming.

Comment: @JayDesai If you say live is working and not on, that means you are loading the scripts prior to the HTML load.  You are not loading the script on document ready. I have updated my answer to run the script on document ready, Use it and let me know if it fixes the issue. Also tell me where have you placed the script block?? after the HTML or before it? Also let me know if your HTML is built dynamically using jquery or not.

Comment: Now popup window is coming but when i click to same image button second time popup window is not coming up. I have put the script in head and also checked by putting in separate script file but issue remains same.

Comment: The issue is obvious, You cannot apply plugin twice to the same element. `$(this).closest('td').find(".dialog").dialog({` applies plugin to the div for every button click. This will not work if you click the button again. As it is trying to apply plugin to already applied element. Also I thought you were trying to apply plugin when button is clicked. I didnt know you just wanted the popup for each button click.

Comment: @JayDesai can you give me the link to the documentation of the plugin you are using??

Comment: yes i want show popup each time when i click to image button. which plugins are u talking about?

Comment: `.dialog` is not default functionalities available in Jquery.. So this plugin must be added. So it will be helpful if you can provide more info on this plugin

Comment: ok leave it, I think you are using `jquery-ui.js` . I will come back with solution

Comment: Its not working may be because u removed image id a,b,c,d. However i have updated my code and popup is coming up in every click but in the same page i have 2 links which technically open another webpage but when i click on that link its open popup window only.

Comment: I am not using the `id` to bind the events I am using class.. Your id is not required at all for this solution. I dont understand what is not working.. What error do you get when you use my solution?

Comment: i got this error `Line: 4 Error: HierarchyRequestError`